# EF4 search page optional fields with lambdas

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, lambda

I've reviewed some of the questions already on SO and tried Google but came up short with getting this to work. I have a search page where a user can enter and select drop downs with anywhere from 0 to 10 fields being filled out. (it is possible to return "all" the results). It's working well until I have a field that allows for multiple selections

```
<select name="area" size="25" multiple="multiple">
    <option>foo</option>
    <option>bar</option>
    <option>baz</option>
    <!--blah blah blah-->
</select>
<input name="someField"/>
```

I'm having trouble translating this to a EF lambda statement. Imagine that the user selects `foo` and `baz` and inputs `42` into the `someField` box. The search should return results for `area` having either and have the correct value for `someField`.

```
//...
var entities = db.entities;
//... this is inside of a switch/loop through the forms collection
string value = Request.Form[key];
//...
If (area <> "") {
    string[] areaSplit = value.Split(',');
    foreach (string s in subSplit)
    {
        string temp = s;
        entities.Where(x => x.area.Contains(temp)); //1
    }
}
//...
entities.Where(x => x.someField == value);
```

so where `//1` is the where shouldn't be exclusive. In other words `entities.area` could have one of any of the values from form field `area`. In a SQL query I would likely write

```
... someField = 42 and (area = 'foo' or area = 'baz')
```

Is it better (efficient, best practice) to just write a SQL query instead?

**Edit** using predicatebuilder

```
var outer = PredicateBuilder.True<entity>();
var inner = PredicateBuilder.False<entity>();

//... this is inside of a switch/loop through the forms collection
string value = Request.Form[key];
//...
string[] areaSplit = value.Split(',');

foreach (string s in subSplit)
{
    string temp = s;
    inner = inner.Or(x => x.area.Contains(temp)); //1
}
//..
outer = outer.And(x => x.someField == value);
//...end of loop
outer.And(inner.Expand());
var foo = db.entity.AsExpandable().Where(outer.Expand());
```

however it seems that it's ignoring the `inner` part. SQL profiler doesn't show the `inner` query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `Contains` the other way around:

```
string[] areaSplit = value.Split(',');
entities = entities.Where(x => areaSplit.Contains(x.area)); //1
entities = entities.Where(x => x.someField == value);
```

This will be translated in an `IN` clause in sql:

```
WHERE (area IN (N'foo', N'baz')) AND (42 = someField)
```

Answer (score 0):

Eonasdan,

I would advise that you take a look at the predicatebuilder from:

http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

this is a realy nice comprehensive way of building up dynamic filters exactly as you describe.

Comment: I did tried predicatebuilder before. I've updated my question with my attempts with that

Answer (score -1):

Eonasdan,

In the method that returns the query results

```
public virtual ActionResult QueryWithMultipleParameters(int param1, int param2, int param3, ...)
{
    var query = dataContext.EntityToQuery;

    if(param1 > 0)
    {
        query = query.Where(e => e.param1 == param1);
    }
    if(param2 > 0)
    {
        query = query.Where(e => e.param2 == param2);
    }
    .... etc. 
    return query; 
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: that's what I'm doing already, but as I noted the multiselect field does not contain **all** selected values. Each result will have **one** of the options selected. This method will simply filter it down expecting the column to have all the values

Comment: @Eonasdan didn't notice that. Sorry. I assumed you had an option of 'all' with a value of zero.

Comment: well yes there is an "all" option for that field, but that's not the problem. the problem is that query the database multiple rows should be returned. the `area` column should return a row that contains any of the selected options